# Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) when use worker

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

when use worker got this error Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) otherwise its works fine in the Production environment.
The only issue in worker through create the record and sending the mail on Production environment

Comment: Error Is related to: your connection Is trying to use a password where Is not needed

Comment: I think sidekiq uses development mode but I am using it in the Production environment.

Comment: I solve this issue :)

Comment: Consider post your answer